# open form from different company ax 2012

Tags: forms, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

Is there a way to open a form within a different company?

I have a form data source that is cross company enabled.  The currently selected record is in Company A.  When I click a menu item is there a way to open that form in Company B?

Or what would be a good alternative to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look how the standard application does this for intercompany functionality. Basically you wrap the code that calls the form in a [changeCompany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa860755.aspx) statement. Take a look at class `TradeInterCompany`, method `formRun` for an example.